# How to use UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following code written in Swift 2.2:

```
let keyData = NSMutableData(length: 64)!
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 64, UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(keyData.mutableBytes))
```

XCode 8 highlights that second line and claims that

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<_>' with an
>   argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'

While I appreciate XCode telling me this, I don't quite understand how to change the UnsafeMutableRawPointer to be acceptable.

Does anyone know how to convert this code into Swift 3?

Comment: I met this problem too. Did you find any solution yet?

Comment: To avoid duplicates, this is my question, very similar with yours. Hope someone can answer my question together with yours. `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafePointer<_>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer?)'`

Comment: Other than OOper's answer, nope. Do you have to use NSMutableData in your case?

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658553/how-to-get-pixel-color-at-location-from-uiimage-scaled-within-a-uiimageview). I just solved my problem with this solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I recommend you to work with `Data` rather than `NSData` in Swift 3.

```
var keyData = Data(count: 64)
let result = keyData.withUnsafeMutableBytes {mutableBytes in
    SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, keyData.count, mutableBytes)
}
```

`withUnsafeMutableBytes(_:)` is declared as a generic method, so, in simple cases such as this, you can use it without specifying element type.

Comment: please see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45181614/cannot-invoke-initializer-for-type-unsafepointer-with-an-argument-list-of-typ