# Cannot invoke initializer for type unsafemutablepointer<Int8> with an argument list of type (UnsafeMutableRawPointer) Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode

After migration to Swift 3 I have a problem with this code:

```
let cipherText = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(cipherData.mutableBytes)
```

Error

> Cannot invoke initializer for type unsafemutablepointer with an argument list of type (UnsafeMutableRawPointer) Swift 3

How to fix this?

Comment: See for example this: [How to use UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515173/how-to-use-unsafemutablepointer-in-swift-3).