# How to convert byte array to base64 string in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, pointers, base64

Here is my sample code in objective C

```
 -(NSString *)getImageString : (unsigned char *) charValue : (unsigned long) sizeOfBytes {                   

    uint8_t commandbyte[]={ };          

    uint8_t _allBytes[(sizeOfBytes + sizeof(commandbyte))];
    memcpy(_allBytes, charValue, sizeOfBytes);

    NSMutableData *ImageData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
    [ImageData appendBytes:_allBytes length:sizeof(_allBytes)];

    NSString *base64String=[self base64forData:ImageData];

    return base64String;                     
}                  

- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {           

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;

        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
                value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
            }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] = table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] = table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

In this example i used to get the `bytes` using the `sizeOfBytes` and then `appendBytes` to `NSMutableData`.

Below method is used to convert `data` to `base64`:

```
- (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData
```

It is very simple in objective C,  but when i tried in swift there other concepts for pointers like `UnsafeMutablePointer`, `UnsafePointer` etc.

How to convert to swift 3.0 ??

Can you Guys please suggest me the usage of pointers in swift

Comment: Use Data, read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515173/how-to-use-unsafemutablepointer-in-swift-3

Comment: What's your actual purpose? You want to practice how to work with Swift `Data` and pointers, even if you know you can use the `base64EncodedString` method?

Answer (score 15):

You can convert bytes array to base64String by using following way

```
let base64String = data!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Comment: What 'type' is the data object in this example?

Answer (score -1):

Swift 5  Convert bytes array to base64String using following ways

Example 1

```swift
let plainText = "Hello world!"
print("Plain Text:", plainText)
print("Base64String:", Array(plainText.utf8).toBase64()!)
```

Output Example 1

```
Plain Text: Hello world!
Base64String: SGVsbG8gd29ybGQh
```

Example 2

```swift
let ivBase64str = "AbcnmWikMkW4c7+mHtwtfw=="
let iv = [UInt8](base64: ivBase64str)
print("BytesArray:", iv)
print("Base64String:", iv.toBase64()!)
```

Output Example 2

```
BytesArray: [1, 183, 39, 153, 104, 164, 50, 69, 184, 115, 191, 166, 30, 220, 45, 127]
Base64String: AbcnmWikMkW4c7+mHtwtfw==
```

Comment: "Extraneous argument label 'base64:' in call" given for example 2

Comment: can you include the `.toBase64()` function definition or documentation of where it came from