# generating random Int64 + swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3

We are getting warnings in the below code. Can anyone suggest what's wrong and what the correct approach would be?

```
class func getRandomInt64() -> Int64 {
    var randomNumber: Int64 = 0
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &randomNumber, { (randomNumberPointer) -> Void in
        let castedPointer = unsafeBitCast(randomNumberPointer, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.self)
         _ = SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 8, castedPointer)
    })
    return abs(randomNumber)
}
```

Earlier it was fine now it's giving the warning:

> 'unsafeBitCast' from 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to 'UnsafeMutablePointer' changes pointee type and may lead to undefined behavior; use the 'withMemoryRebound' method on 'UnsafeMutablePointer' to rebind the type of memory

Comment: i Just test your code and it's working properly there is no issue

Comment: @BhupatBheda You are not testing this on Swift 3 then.

Comment: @Oskar i had tried this but i didn't get error might be you got i got random like Result is :-6809176430944439855

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515173/how-to-use-unsafemutablepointer-in-swift-3)

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3 introduced `withMemoryRebound`, replacing `unsafeBitCast` and other unsafe casts: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafepointer/2430863-withmemoryrebound

The correct way to use it in your case:

```
class func getRandomInt64() -> Int64 {
    var randomNumber: Int64 = 0
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &randomNumber, { (randomNumberPointer) -> Void in
        _ = randomNumberPointer.withMemoryRebound(to: UInt8.self, capacity: 8, { SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 8, $0) })
    })
    return abs(randomNumber)
}
```

Comment: capacity should be 8 shouldn't it?  As in 8 `UInt8`s makes one `UInt64`

Comment: Also not sure about `randomNumber = Int64(castedPointer)` since `castedPointer` points at `randomNumber` and thus `randomNumber` already is filled in.
        `

Comment: Thanks my warning got disappeared but one question from my end is will the modified code will be doing the same like earlier code ..Please confirm once.

Comment: @JeremyP You are completely correct. I have corrected my answer.
@ author: I've tested it and the code above now works fine. Make sure you use the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks @Oskar for your support

Comment: No problem! If it worked for you, please mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

why not this way?

```
import Foundation

func randomInt64()->Int64 {
    var t = Int64()
    arc4random_buf(&t, MemoryLayout<Int64>.size)
    return t
}

let i = randomInt64()
```

or better with generic

```
import Foundation

func random<T: Integer>()->T {
    var t: T = 0
    arc4random_buf(&t, MemoryLayout<T>.size)
    return t
}

let i:Int = random()
let u: UInt8 = random()
```