# Cannot invoke initializer for type UnsafePointer<_> with an argument list of type (UnsafeMutableRawPointer)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, outputstream, multipeer-connectivity

When I write the output stream in multipeer connectivity from audio buffer data I got the error

> Cannot invoke initializer for type UnsafePointer<_> with an argument
>   list of type (UnsafeMutableRawPointer)

I found the many solutions, but this solution not helpful for me.

My code is:

```
func send(_ buffer: AudioBuffer) {
        print(buffer.mData!)
        print(buffer.mDataByteSize)

        outputStreme?.write(UnsafePointer(buffer.mData), maxLength: buffer.mDataByteSize)
    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance..:)

Comment: you need to work with Data rather than NSData in Swift 3

Comment: @KKRocks I this is unsafe mutable raw pointer but i want unsafe pointer, because it use in output stram argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check the official reference when some sort of spec changes has affected with your code. In your case `AudioBuffer.mData` is of type `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`, and you need to pass it to the first argument of `OutputStream.write(_:maxLength:)` of type `UnsafePointer<UInt8>`.

[UnsafeMutableRawPointer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer)

You can find this method which returns `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`:

[`func assumingMemoryBound<T>(to: T.Type)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2428188-assumingmemorybound)

The concept of *bound* is sort of confusing, but seems you can use it for pointer type conversion:

```
outputStreme?.write(buffer.mData!.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), maxLength: Int(buffer.mDataByteSize))
```

(Assuming forced-unwrapping `!` is safe enough as suggested by your `print(buffer.mData!)`.)

Memory *bound*-ness is not well defined for most APIs which return pointers, and has no effect as for now. There's another type conversion method [`func bindMemory<T>(to: T.Type, capacity: Int)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablerawpointer/2428061-bindmemory), and both work without problems (again, as for now).

Comment: Thank you Sir... You are genius

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
withUnsafePointer(to: &data) {rawUuidPtr in //<- `rawUuidPtr` is of type `UnsafePointer<uuid_t>`.
            let bytes = UnsafeRawPointer(rawUuidPtr).assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self)
            outputStream.write(bytes, maxLength: 4)
        }
```