# How to get non-rectangular shaped button?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

How can I get a non-rectangular shaped button?

I have a `UIImage` with a mask. How can I set the shape of a button to this image without the transparent color.

[image]

Comment: What is the part of this image that you want to set as a button?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/29767663/285190

Comment: button.layer.cornerRadius

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a UIImage with a mask. How can I set the shape of a button to this image without the transparent color.

Buttons are controls, and controls are views, and views are inherently rectangular, so a button will always occupy a rectangular space in the view hierarchy. However, the visible part of a view (and therefore a button) can be whatever you want it to be... a view can have a transparent background, and can draw itself however it likes. A view can also choose to pretend that a touch event doesn't hit it, potentially making the view *seem* to have a non-rectangular shape for the purpose of delivering touches. You can do that by overriding `hitTest(_:with:)`.

Also, realize that you don't always need to use buttons in order to interact with objects on the screen. If you have an image of a house, for example, and you want the user to be able to tap different parts of the house to change its color or texture, you could display the house in a view that knows where different parts of the house are in the image. You could use gesture recognizers or the normal touch handling mechanism to let the user interact with the different regions, and those regions can be any shape you like.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot. How would I override `hitTest` to tell if point inside is transparent?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... are you asking how to override a method,  or how to implement this particular overridden method?

Comment: I'm asking about this particular method. How would you make `hitTest` ignore transparency?

Comment: I'd look at the alpha value of the [pixel at the point in the image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37965361/643383) where the touch happened and return `nil` if it's below some threshold.